# Undo delete of an ignored file in Git

Tags: git

I tried to fix some merge conflicts in Git, but I deleted my media folder (indirectly), in which I had all the images I needed for my website. I could've pulled from Git, except I can't because .gitignore ignores the media folder.

I pulled from git, but it said

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge.

So I stashed my directory and then tried to pull again. Because of a few merge conflicts, I stashed, committed, and then tried to reset HEAD to the previous commit (I think this is where the folder got deleted) after `git checkout -- .`.

Is there a way I can undo this deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately : the actions you descibe do not include things that would erase untracked files from disk. Your media folder probably ended up in the stash.

Run `git stash list` to inspect how many stashes you have.

You can use regular git commands to inspect the content of a stash. For example, you can list the files in a stash using `git ls-tree` :

```
git ls-tree stash@{xx}
git ls-tree -r --name-only stash@{xx}:media/folder

# actually, 'git ls-tree' works on any commit (not just stashes)
```

If you see the content you want in one of these stashes, just run :

```
git stash apply stash@{xx}

# if its the first stash (stash@{0}), shortcut is :
git stash apply
```

Comment: You can use the friendlier `git show stash@{xx}:` and `git show stash@{xx}:media/folder` , although these do not recurse into directories.

Comment: Not an issue in this particular case, but for anyone coming across these comments later, note that if you had used `git stash -u`, the untracked files are in the *third* stash commit so you would need to look at `stash@{xx}^2` here.